# Having trouble manually setting UITabBar selected Item

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a custom `UITabBar` within a View Controller. I successfully set the `UITabBar` delegate as the `UIViewController`.

However, on viewDidLoad I want to have the first item of the UITabBar selected using:

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items[0] as UITabBarItem
```

but I keep running into this error.

```
(UITabBar, didSelectItem: UITabBarItem) -> ()' does not have a member named 'selectedItem'
```

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tabBar : UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet var placeHolderView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items[0] as UITabBarItem
        switchView(0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        switch item.tag {
        case 0:
            switchView(0)
            break
        case 1:
           switchView(1)
           break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

UPDATE:

got this to work:

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as? UITabBarItem
```

I still have to get my head around optionals...

Comment: any time you see the "does not have a member named" on an object that you're pretty sure does have it, the first thing to check is if your really dealing with an optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution to be working :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]){
      if i.tag == 0 {
        tabBar.selectedItem = i
        break;
      }
    }
    switchView(0)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still curious as to why my initial effort didn't work, however.

Comment: I think that you had to access the `tag` property of the items rather than what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that UITabBar.items is an optional, so you need to unwrap it to access the array.

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This also worked, but I got the warning:

   Treating a forced downcast to 'UITabBarItem' as optional will never produce 'nil'

Comment: Fixed with :

tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as? UITabBarItem